# Windows 7 PowerShell Copy-Item if larger

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to archive an old OSX Aperture photo library to a Windows folder. I want to use Copy-Item to crunch through the complicated nested folder structure and dump them all in a flat folder. I think the following command does most of what I want:

```
PS C:\> Copy-Item -Path E:\ApertureLib\*.jpg -Destination E:\Export -Recurse
```

Sometimes the original JPG is in the folder structure. This is obviously preferable for archiving. There is always a smaller preview in the a subfolder called preview. I want to copy this if the original is not available. The preview and original have the same filename.

So, I need to my command to handle filename collisions like this: If the newer file is larger, overwrite the old. If it isn't, do nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: It will require more than simply updating your command. You will need code that can programmatically handle the name collisions (if file exists in destination: If smaller than file being copied, overwrite; otherwise, skip).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps something like this (not tested):

```
$destination = "E:\Export"
Get-ChildItem "E:\ApertureLib" -Include *.jpg -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
  $destinationName = Join-Path $destination $_.Name
  if ( Test-Path -LiteralPath $destinationName ) {
    $copyTheFile = $_.Length -gt (Get-Item -LiteralPath $destinationName).Length
  }
  else {
    $copyTheFile = $true
  }
  if ( $copyTheFile ) {
    Copy-Item $_ $destinationName -WhatIf
  }
}
```

If this works as expected, you can remove the `-WhatIf` to perform the copy.

Comment: Thanks Bill! The script ran without errors but didn't recurse - only copied files in the root of the folder specified.

Comment: Perform troubleshooting. Run the `Get-ChildItem ... -Recurse` command by itself and see what it outputs.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. It's working now with `Get-ChildItem "E:\ApertureLib\" -include *.jpg -Recurse` (apparently -include is required when recursing).